# Joomla json output comoponent 2.5 from controller to view

Tags: php, json, variables, joomla, components

I have a qeustion for you, Ive got a JSON Api which give me some info, some of it isn't usefull.

With the following line of code i can call all info and write into my view:

```
    $url = 'http://apisurl.com/prequalify/json/'.$postcode.'/'.$huisnummer.'';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content);
```

Send it to view:

```
$view->assignRef('info', $content);
```

This is my normal PHP code:

```
foreach ($json['enduserinfo'] as $item) {
        echo " Postcode: {$item['zipcode']}
        <br /> Huisnummer: {$item['housenr']}
        <br /> Straatnaam: {$item['street']}
        <br /> Woonplaats: {$item['city']}
        <br /> Centrale: {$item['centrale']}
        <br /> Toegangspunt: {$item['access-area']}
        <br /> Isra: {$item['isra']}";
    }
```

How do i get the same result within Joomla?

The real problem for me is that i don't need al info and i would like to setup some variables to store the correct data in. And only send them to my view. Now the result is only a complete JSON file within my page.

Within my normal php script, extern from Joomla it work's fine. Does Joomla got a special way to do this?

Please Help

Comment: why your setting $content in the assignref you just parse that and required data set as an array in assignref.

Comment: are you using jquery in your view?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I am not using JQuery.

Comment: @jobinjose I have searched how to declare the array but won't work for me. Could you give me a example on how to convert it in a array? Cause when i try my only output is, "{".

Comment: @JSkirMan $array_name = array(); or simple you can use a veriable it will consider as array.

Comment: jsut do: $myarr =  json_decode($content,true)

Comment: {"enduserinfo":[{"zipcode":"5126NW","housenr":"6","housenr_ext":"","street":"OMLOOP","city":"GILZE","centrale":"Gz","access-area":"AA\/38","isra":"001\/\/\/"}],"dsl":[{"network":"KPN","technology":"ADSL2+_POTS","availability":"Green","bw-up":"1025","bw-down":"16001"}],"vdsl":[{"network":"KPN","technology":"VDSL2_POTS","availability":"Red","bw-down":"","bw-up":""}],"fttc":[{"network":"KPN","technology":"VDSL2","availability":"Red","bw-down":"","bw-up":""}],"ftth":[{"network":"KPN","technology":"EoF","availability":"Red","bw-down":"","bw-up":""}]}

Comment: Above you guys see my json output. I need the zipcode from the enduserinfo. @mamdouhalramadan The only output i get with $zipcode = json_decode($content,true) = array

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan But if i see ure example, it's exactly what i did before. See 3rd line in 1st example in my qeustion.

Comment: you have to set **true** so it will be assiociative array. - @JSkirMan

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan ok but how do i strip down this array? Cause now my only output is array?? I posted my JSon output for you, which already showed up on site.

Comment: @JSkirMan - depends on the keys you want, you can use foreach loop or any other loop.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan like i showed in my qeustion ?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan did something wrong in my view, beginner's mistake i suppose. Works now, needed to add $this->zipcode in my frontend instead of $json as showed in my qeustion. Please forgive me :$ Thanks for time and patience..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you should do the following:

```
$myJson = json_decode($content, true); // will make it as associative array
$theIndexIwantToSendToTheView = $myJson['enduserinfo'];
//send to view the variable $theIndexIwantToSendToTheView
```

Now you can process the **json** using the variable `$myJson`

this will solve your problem.